# Lists to numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.6

Why does the following code generate a numpy array with lists printed inside the array for list3?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hUvf.png)
Output observed:

```
list2=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] #list of 3 lists makes 3 rows and 3 
columns for numpy array
#each list fills one row
print('List2',list2)
print('List2 casted as 3x3 array',np.array(list2))

list3=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
print(np.array(list3))
```

Comment: Because it has variable number of elements per "subarray". For those cases results in array of lists.