# how to convert nested list into numpy array?

Tags: numpy, python-3.7

In my code when I am taking nested array of list length of 100, I am getting the correct 3D numpy array as output, but when I write code to get numpy array of list length of 1000 or above, I am getting wrong numpy array (i.e. it shows it as single dimensional rather than 3 dimensional).

I tried using numpy.array(list) and numpy.asarray(list), but both have same output.

expected output is array with dimensions(1000,50,100) but actual output is array with dimensions(1000,1).

Comment: I think there are some mistakes in your list, please check the dtype of the result array.

Comment: In the longer case one or more of the lists has a different length.  The result is an array of lists, with `object` dtype.

Comment: See this similar case with example lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455371/lists-to-numpy-array

Comment: By mistake, one list was of different length. Thank you. It solved the problem.